# Metro UI Exploration

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I searched through internet but couldn't find a satisfactory answer about Metro UI , Are those tiles are called Metro UI. Is that much hype is about only tiles and flash like applications ?
What is Metro UI?

Comment: You can install win8 on a virtual box and see for yourself http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-install-windows-8-on-virtualbox/

Comment: i have done that and i didnt find anything in metro app but a better flash application may be i am worng so if someone enlighten me what exactly is Metro UI except tiles and page navigation kaida stuff that would be much better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metro UI are not just tiles, the metro design is an idea of how to design user interfaces, and how to improve the user experience. There are a lot of principles in metro, but I think the leading one is content not chrome. There are a lot of articles out in the web, I can advise this one http://www.stephanemassey.com/metro-design-principles/